# Open a new activity for each button of the GridView

Tags: android, android-intent, android-button, onclicklistener

This is my Custom `OnClickListener`. I am passing the position of my my Gridview button from the `ButtonAdapter.class`. I want to open a new activity for each button of the grid view. What changes should I make in my `MyOnClickListener.class`?

MyOnClickListener.class

```
import android.content.Intent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;

public class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {


private final int position;  

    public MyOnClickListener(int position)  
    {  
        this.position = position;  
    }  

    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), WordsList.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
    }

}
```

I got the Solution. I tried this and it Works!

```
public class MyOnClickListener implements OnClickListener {


private final int position;  

public MyOnClickListener(int position)  
{  
    this.position = position;  
}  

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(position){
        case 0:
        Intent a = new Intent(v.getContext(), WordsList.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(a);
        break;
    case 1:
        Intent b = new Intent(v.getContext(), About.class);
        v.getContext().startActivity(b);
        break;  

    }


}

}
```

Comment: What problems are you facing now ?

Comment: problem is solved. I used the switch(position){case 0:....}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Or something like :

```
private Class[] activities = {
    Activity1.class,   // position=0
    Activity2.class,   // position=1
    //...
    };

public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), activities[position]);
    v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
}
```

But that's very simple, and maybe I missed the point ?

Answer (score 1):

```
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
 Intent intent; 
 switch(v.getId())
 {
    case R.id.btn1:
       intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), WordsList1.class);
       v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
       break;
    case R.id.btn2:
       intent = new Intent(v.getContext(), WordsList2.class);
       v.getContext().startActivity(intent);
       break;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you should be using a OnItemClickListener, as it's specialised for adapter based UIs.
It will pass to you besides the view itself (like in the OnClick), but also position and ID that will make it easy to identify the caller and act properly on it.